# Where should I ask a question about process modeling?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I need advice considering business process modeling notations and tools, namely, B2B process integration modelling (tools, notations, comparison etc).

I'm not sure this is a topic for Stack Overflow, but it is closely related to software and informational technologies. So - where could I get some help regarding this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) has a [bpm](/questions/tagged/bpm) tag and various [BPM questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bpm) so depending on the exact questions you're asking they're most likely to be [on-topic there](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there if they're on topic anywhere.